# ORA-01036 error, when binding variables with cx_oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

When trying to address a function and binding some params, im constantly getting strange result

I've tried to use different variable names and different numbers in vars, but no luck

```py
        res_sum = -1
        good_id = 430815501
        self.cur.prepare(":smth := AP_USER_OFFICE_PKG_S.GET_SERVS_SUMS(:smth2).N_GOOD_SUM;")

        self.cur.execute(None, {'smth': res_sum, 'smth2': good_id})
```

I'm  expecting function to return result, but getting only

```
    self.cur.execute(None, {'smth': res_sum, 'smth2': good_id})
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    def get_service_sum(self, good_id):
        SQL_BLOCK = '''
        DECLARE
            v_good_id    NUMBER;
            v_result  NUMBER;
        BEGIN
            v_good_id := :i_good_id;
            v_result := AP_USER_OFFICE_PKG_S.GET_SERVS_SUMS(v_good_id).N_GOOD_SUM;
            :o_result := v_result;  -- (1)
        END;

        '''
        res_sum = self.cur.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
        good_id = 430815501

        self.cur.execute(SQL_BLOCK, i_good_id=good_id, o_result=res_sum)
        res = res_sum.getvalue()  # (4)
        return res
```

Finally found a solution by myself) I hope this will be useful for next generations)